# In "связанных с его лечением", is связанных an adjective or a participle?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, глаголы

Take this sentence:

> Но похоже, что русским настолько неприятна мысль о геморрое и
>   сложностях, **связанных с его лечением**, что они решили называть этим
>   словом любые трудности, с которыми сталкиваются.

I assume связанных is the prepositional plural of связанный, but is it a declension of связанный the adjective or связанный the past passive participle of the verb связать?

Comment: The question is, whether this is an adjective or a _participle_ (причастие). There are answers below, but it may comfort you to know that you are not alone. This is one of the most tricky questions even for Russian students. Correct spelling (using `-н-` or `-нн-`) and sometimes punctuation depends on the answer. For example: `вязаный свитер` (прилагательное) but `вязанный по-домашнему свитер` (причастие).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[an article on the difference between participles and adjectives](http://thedifference.ru/otlichie-prilagatelnogo-ot-prichastiya/)

lists 5 counts of difference

> 1. Прилагательное является самостоятельной частью речи. Причастие представляет собой особую форму глагола.
> 2. `Прилагательные имеют разряды по значению и делятся на качественные, относительные и притяжательные. Причастия не имеют такой характеристики.`
> 3. Причастие обладает морфологическими признаками прилагательного и глагола.
> 4. У прилагательного глагольных признаков быть не может.
> 5. `Прилагательные образуются от имен существительных. Причастия – от основы глагола.`
> 6. Прилагательные, в отличие от причастий, не могут иметь зависимых слов в предложении.

Judging by these principles `связанный` is a participle

Comment: П. 5 неверен. Существуют и отглагольные прилагательные. П.1 вообще ни о чем.

Comment: Согласен: П.5 неверен. П.2 тоже не догоняю, честно говоря, примеры бы посмотреть?

Comment: with regard to P2 examples of these types of adjectives are given in the referenced article. the most striking and easy to understand difference between participle and adjective is exemplified by qualitative (качественными) adjectives, because they have comparative and superlative modes, we can say `более тёплый/менее тёплый/самый тёплый` but we can't, or maybe only in very specific cases, say `более связанный/менее связанный/` and especially `самый связанный`, likewise a phrase `твой свитер более вязаный, чем мой` sounds oddly

Comment: as for P5 i believe many adjectives originated as participles and then lost immediate connection with the verb'al origin, yet at their core they remain participles

Comment: @Баян Купи-ка Ссылка у меня не открывается. Судя по процитированному, источник доверия не заслуживает. Кто автор? В интернетах много чего пишут, как известно.   "believe many adjectives originated as participles" - well, then P.5 should at least mention that adjectives can originate from participles, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is "the past passive participle of the verb связать". Actually, I might have lost some of my Russian grammar, but I feel that the word 'past' is redundant here as I struggle to think of a 'present passive participle' from 'связать'.
The construction is called 'причастный оборот', it follows the noun it relates to ('сложностях') and is embraced in commas.

Comment: 'present passive participle' from 'связать' would be 'связываемый'

Comment: так точно - тормознул. А точнее... хм, это ведь от глагола "связывать", а не "связать" (несоверш.вид vs соверш.вид).

Comment: Пожалуй, да....

Comment: @Zeus Не забанили б меня за флуд, но тема "Причастия", кажется, была в моём экзаменационном билете на выпукном экзамене в 8-м классе (это было очень давно :)) Возможно, благодаря этому я до сих пор помню такие понятия, как действительное/страдательное и прошедшего/настоящего времени. ("связывать": связывающий, связываемый, связывавший... а страдательное-прошедшее - никак(?). С соверш.видом всё хитрее. "связать": связующий, связанный .. и всё(?) )

Answer (score 1):

You cannot form an adjective from a perfective verb, only a participle.

There are some idiomatic adjectives (*назва́ный, смышлёный, посажёный*) which are historically perfective participles, however, they are fossils.

*Связанный* is a participle.

Comment: Yup, edited my answer. А с другой стороны - вот тут некий онлайновый морфологический разбор даёт оба варианта :) Что скажете? http://morphologyonline.ru/связанный

Comment: @A.Toumantsev: it's wrong. Adjectives differ from participles by defining some quality rather than process. *варёная сгущёнка* and *копчёное мясо* might not have been subject to boiling or smoking, say, if they have been treated by pressure steaming or liquid smoke; *варённая сгущёнка* and *копчённое мясо* by definition have been boiled and smoked. Perfective verbs are about state transition, so it's always about process.

Comment: Мне, наверное, не стоило заходить в эту ветку - запутался ещё больше :) Поиск показывает, что чуть ли не все "онлайн морф. разборы" утверждают, что "связанный" может быть и причастием, и прилагательным: https://how-to-all.com/морфология:связанный.  Ну и "варёННая сгущёнка" мне режет глаз, так как нет "зависимого слова" ("вАренная в кастрюле картошка"), и потому видеть двойную "н" очень странно.